# Funny behavior of Underscore template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I try to pass data immediately to template call:
 `var compiled = _.template('template code there', {params: 123})`

And regards to specs the variable 'compiled' must be ready to use as HTML markup.

But! I got a function..

It's really strange for me.. I ran this code at plnkr.co, and it gave expecting result, but locally it's not working as expected.

p.s. In my example I use bower to download scripts

```
<script src="../scripts/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/vendor/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/vendor/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
```

...

```
var list = "<%= ... %>";
    var compiled = _.template(list, {data : ['one', 'two']});
alert(compiled); // got function !
```

Can anybody explain this?

P.S. worked example - http://jsfiddle.net/xm6ymxoj/
and I can't reproduce this simple code locally on my machine, as result I receive a function (in alert).

Comment: Are you using the same version?

Answer (score 2):

`_.template(templateString, [settings])` (see [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#template)) compiles a string to a template. This template is a function that can then be rendered to HTML with some given data.

From the docs:

```
var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
compiled({name: 'moe'});
=> "hello: moe"
```

**EDIT:** So in your example you should use:

```
var list = "<%= ... %>";
var compiled = _.template(list);
var html = compiled({data: ['one', 'two']})
```

Comment: Yes, but it's also possible to pass data in _template call immediately. `c_markup = _.template("Hello <%=user%>!", { user: "<Jane>" });
 alert(c_markup);` - It's works well, but not for my local server .. and I can't understand why

Comment: As far as I know, the settings object can contain settings for `escape`, `interpolate`, `evaluate` and `variable`. No data. See the [default templateSettings](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1398) and [_.template](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1430)

Comment: I add complete example [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xm6ymxoj/) what I mean

Comment: Apparently this has been removed [in 1.7.0](http://underscorejs.org/#changelog): "Underscore templates no longer accept an initial data object. _.template always returns a function now."

Answer (score 0):

It's many code examples in network something like this one:

```
 var c_markup = _.template("Hello <%=user%>!", { user: "MyName" });
```

But as I understand this code is obsolete, and not worked now.

We need to pass parameters to prepared function call:

```
var c_markup = _.template("Hello <%=user%>!");
c_markup({ user: "MyName" });
```

This moment was confused me. Hope this can helps someone.